# Delete parts of sequential files in folders in windows

Tags: batch, python

I need to find a way to delete parts of sequences of files. For example in specific folder I have several subfolders, which contain:

```
blabla_0001.jpg
blabla_0002.jpg
blabla_0003.jpg
blabla_0004.jpg
dada_0001.jpg
dada_0002.jpg
dada_0003.jpg
dada_0004.jpg
dada_0005.jpg
```

I want to delete all files `*0003.jpg` to `*0005.jpg` in all subfolders. My knowledge of python and Windows batch is limited. I use Windows 7.

Comment: at least you can try search for 0003 directly in windows, and delete results.

Comment: Type `del /?` in command line window. `del /S "x:\specific folder\*0003.jpg"` might help.

Comment: Yes you can, except that the range I need to delete is from 0151 to 0580 for example. And for several prefixes and subfolders. In total in guess I need to delete 100.000+ files.

Comment: like this, but for pc: http://askubuntu.com/questions/529270/how-can-i-delete-numbered-files-in-a-given-range

Comment: Improve regex in `dir /B /S | findstr /R ".*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.jpg$"` [to match your criteria](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html); Then use `FOR /F` against improved `dir`...

Comment: For defined range, try `for /L %G in (151,1,159) do @echo del /S *_0%G.jpg`

Comment: I have this:@echo off

dir /B /S | findstr /R ".*_00_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.dpx$"
for /L %%G in (541,1,550) DO @echo del /S *_00_000%%G.dpx but does not delete them

Comment: @FabianESH: Naturally that command will not delete anything until you remove the `@echo` before the `del`.

Comment: Yeah, thx!!!! It works.